# ShapeDrawable add in LinearLayout can not useless

Tags: android

i hava create `DotView` extend `View`,such as:

```
 private ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    mWidth = getWidth();
    mHeight = getHeight();

    if(mWidth>=mHeight){
        circleDiameter=mHeight/3;
    }else{
        circleDiameter=mWidth/3;
    }

    left = (mWidth - circleDiameter) / 2;
    top = (mHeight - circleDiameter) / 2;
    right = left + circleDiameter;
    bottom = top + circleDiameter;

    super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    canvas.drawLine(0, 0, this.getWidth() - 1, 0, paint);
    canvas.drawLine (0, 0, 0, this.getHeight () - 1, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(this.getWidth() - 1, 0, this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1, paint);
    canvas.drawLine(0, this.getHeight() - 1, this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1, paint);
    mDrawable.setBounds (left, top, right, bottom);
    mDrawable.getPaint().setColor (Color.BLACK);
    mDrawable.draw (canvas);
}
```

just use `DotView` in xml can desplay:

[image]

than i create a `PasswordBox` extend `LinearLayout` and add six `DotView`:

```
 private int mPwdSize = 6;

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure (widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setOrientation (HORIZONTAL);
    for(int i = 0; i < mPwdSize; i++) {
        DotView dotView = new DotView (getContext ());
        LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams (getWidth ()/6,getHeight ());
        addView (dotView, layoutParams);
    }
}
```

but it dosen't work! the ShapeDrawable can not desplay. look picture:

[image]

i don't know where code has problem,please help me.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem. so stupid,`getWidth()` is 0, should be use `getMeasuredWidth()`